# How can I load csv files as separate dataframe from a S3 bucket in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def get_s3_keys(bucket, prefix):

    """Get a list of keys in an S3 bucket."""
    resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    for obj in resp['Contents']:
      files = obj['Key']
      print(files)
    return files


filename = get_s3_keys('bucket', 'folder')
print(filename)
```

I use the above function to get the keys and I see 3 csv files. I want them to be imported into separate datframes.

Comment: Like using `Pandas`?

Comment: yes using pandas

Answer (score 1):

I have three files on my S3: `airtravel.csv, cities.csv, tally_cab.csv`, which were taken from [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/csv/csv.html).

I use this:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

my_bucket = "eine-spinne"
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=my_bucket)

dfs = {}
for file in resp['Contents']:
    key = file['Key']
    if key.endswith(".csv"):
        object_data = s3.get_object(Bucket=my_bucket, Key=key)
        dfs[key] = pd.read_csv(object_data['Body'])

print(type(dfs['airtravel.csv']), "\n", dfs['airtravel.csv'].iloc[0])
```

This creates a `dict` of three dataframes where S3 files are keys.

Sample output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
 Month      JAN
 "1958"    340
 "1959"    360
 "1960"    417
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: This answer assumes we have to concatenate the files but we should not and also the bucket has several directories. So I want to just import the files that are in a specific folder separately.

Comment: You didn't mention any of this in your question. You explicitly say that there are three files and you want them in three data-frames. Also, the solution *doesn't* concatenate anything. Use `Prefix` to get files from specific folders.

Comment: If you have already installed s3fs (pip install s3fs) then you can read the file directly from s3 path, without any imports: `data = pd.read_csv('s3:/bucket....csv')`